# How do I recover deleted entries from Xubuntu Settings Manager?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, settings

While playing with the "Edit Menu" (Application menu), I deleted some entries for settings (like "Display", "Appearance", "Desktop" etc.). This also deleted the entries in the Settings Manager.

**How can I put them back?**

Xubuntu 12.10 - Xfce 4.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a good one, as there is no documentation on what to do when this happens. Deleting *Display* or *Accessibility*, for example, from the Accessories part of the Xfce4 menu will actually **remove** the helper application's link from settings manager.

What happens is that when you 'delete' something like accessibility from the Accessories part of the Xfce4 menu, a `.desktop` file appears in `~/.local/share/applications`. That file will be labelled, for example, `xfce4-accessibility-settings.desktop` and will have in the file:

```
Exec=xfce4-accessibility-settings
Hidden=true
```

So therefore just delete the `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications` that refer to the Xfce items that you have deleted in the menu dialog: e.g. `xfce-display-settings.desktop`.

Now when you load up the settings manager again they will be available once more. The 'applications' in settings manager are just links to those applications: e.g. `xfce4-accessibility-settings` is the program behind the accessibility icon.

If you want to get a list of the settings programs for reference, run

```
dpkg -L xfce4-settings | grep bin
```

which returns:

```
/usr/bin/xfce4-settings-editor
/usr/bin/xfce4-mouse-settings
/usr/bin/xfsettingsd
/usr/bin/xfce4-keyboard-settings
/usr/bin/xfce4-settings-manager
/usr/bin/xfce4-display-settings
/usr/bin/xfce4-accessibility-settings
/usr/bin/xfce4-mime-settings
/usr/bin/xfce4-appearance-settings
```

I can say that the solution has been tested on Xfce 4.10 and 4.12 (development) and will work. However, reinstalling the Xfce components would not work, as the problem lies in your home folder, of which files and settings are not purged when reinstalling programs.

Comment: That was an excellent answer! It worked like a charm. Thank you! 

I think that this problem should be prevented some way, as it is supposed to delete only entries in the Applications Menu.